# How to avoid long waitngs from JAX-WS web service on client side?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I need to implement a web service which do the following steps:

1. receives requests from web service A
2. sends request to web service B
3. sends response from wevservice B to web service A

In case if my web service didn't receive response from B after 5 seconds it has to send appropriate answer to A and to stop waiting for an answer from B.

I've generated client for web service B using wsimport tool. So as I understand I should set timeout for generated client. Am I right?
I've found the following solution for this:

```
((BindingProvider)portB).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", "1000");
((BindingProvider)portB).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", "1000");
```

But I don't like this solution because of two reasons:

**1. It doesn't work for me**

I wrote simple service B emulator which receives response from my web service and sends mock answer back. And to test timeout I am adding this code to mock service B:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);       
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

And this test shows that those lines with putting properties to BindingProvider doesn't work. My web service just waits all those 15 seconds instead of stop after 1 second.
I've seen few other variants of name for those parameters (some of them where intended for JBoss and Glassfish) but none of them works for me. 
I am using Tomcat 8 as application server for mock service B.

**2. It isn't universal for all application servers.**

As I understand there are unique timeout parameter's names for every application server. And if web service B stands on JBoss then I should use

```
((BindingProvider)portB).getRequestContext().put(TIMEOUT_PARAMS_NAME_FOR_JBOSS, "2000");
```

But if web service B stands on WebSphere than I shoud use

```
((BindingProvider)portB).getRequestContext().put(TIMEOUT_PARAMS_NAME_FOR_WEBSPHERE, "2000");
```

And so on.
But what if I just don't know which application server is used by web service B? I am a little-bit confused about this moment. Maybe I just misunderstand something?

So what is the right way to avoid long waitings for a response from web service B in my case?

Comment: Did you try adding to the requestContext `BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT and
BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` ?

Comment: Now I tried and it works. Thank you.
But am I right that those constants are intended only to Tomcat app server? 
If web service B will stand on WebSphere or on JBoss will those constants working?